# XSLT 1.0: Group items with similar tag values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm a bit new to XSLT and I'm trying to group up the child elements that are having similar value for a particular tag. Really appreciate your help.

For example, my data structure looks something like this:

```
<root>
    <Persons xmlns:p="http://test1.com" xmlns:pid="http://test1.com/person">
        <Person>
            <Data xmlns="http://test1.com/person">
                <personId>12345</personId>
                <dsId>DS_1</dsId>
                <data>data1</data>
                <ts>2014-09-22</ts>
            </Data>
            <Data xmlns="http://test1.com/person">
                <personId>12345</personId>
                <dsId>DS_2</dsId>
                <data>data2</data>
                <ts>2014-09-22</ts>
            </Data>
            <Data xmlns="http://test1.com/person">
                <personId>12345</personId>
                <dsId>DS_3</dsId>
                <data>data3</data>
                <ts>2014-09-22</ts>
            </Data>
            <Data xmlns="http://test1.com/person">
                <personId>12345</personId>
                <dsId>DS_3</dsId>
                <data>data4</data>
                <ts>2014-09-23</ts>
            </Data>
            <details xmlns="http://test1.com">
                <personId>12345</personId>
            </details>
        </Person>
    </Persons>
</root>
```

I want to group `<Data>` items from their `<dsId>` value and transform above xml into the below structure.

```
<personData xmlns="http://test1.com/personData" xmlns:p="http://test1.com" xmlns:pid="http://test1.com/person">
   <matchedResults>
      <person>
         <details>
            <personID xmlns="http://test1.com/person">12345</personID>
         </details>
         <dataSourceResults>
            <ds id="DS_1" name="DS_1">
               <result loadedTimestamp="2014-09-22">
                  <entry>data1</entry>
               </result>
            </ds>
            <ds id="DS_2" name="DS_2">
               <result loadedTimestamp="2014-09-22">
                  <entry>data2</entry>
               </result>
            </ds>
            <ds id="DS_3" name="DS_3">
               <result loadedTimestamp="2014-09-22">
                  <entry>data3</entry>
               </result>
               <result loadedTimestamp="2014-09-23">
                  <entry>data4</entry>
               </result>
            </ds>
         </dataSourceResults>
      </person>
   </matchedResults>
</personData>
```

Please note in above output message `<ds id="DS_3"..` element contains two `<result..` node elements.

Here is the closest transform I could come up with(which doesn't do the grouping).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:p="http://test1.com" xmlns:pid="http://test1.com/person">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <personData xmlns="http://test1.com/personData">
            <matchedResults>
                <xsl:for-each select="/root/Persons/Person">
                    <person>
                        <details>
                            <personID xmlns="http://test1.com/person"><xsl:value-of select="p:details/p:personId/text()"/></personID>
                        </details>
                        <dataSourceResults>
                            <xsl:for-each select="pid:Data">
                                <xsl:variable name="dsId" select="translate(pid:dsId/text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
                                <xsl:if test="not($dsId = '')">
                                    <xsl:element name="ds">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="pid:dsId/text()"/></xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="pid:dsId/text()"/></xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:element name="result">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="loadedTimestamp"><xsl:value-of select="pid:ts"/></xsl:attribute>
                                            <entry><xsl:value-of select="pid:data"/></entry>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </dataSourceResults>
                    </person>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </matchedResults>
        </personData>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It only gives me below output.

```
<personData xmlns="http://test1.com/personData" xmlns:p="http://test1.com" xmlns:pid="http://test1.com/person">
   <matchedResults>
      <person>
         <details>
            <personID xmlns="http://test1.com/person">12345</personID>
         </details>
         <dataSourceResults>
            <ds id="DS_1" name="DS_1">
               <result loadedTimestamp="2014-09-22">
                  <entry>data1</entry>
               </result>
            </ds>
            <ds id="DS_2" name="DS_2">
               <result loadedTimestamp="2014-09-22">
                  <entry>data2</entry>
               </result>
            </ds>
            <ds id="DS_3" name="DS_3">
               <result loadedTimestamp="2014-09-22">
                  <entry>data3</entry>
               </result>
            </ds>
            <ds id="DS_3" name="DS_3">
               <result loadedTimestamp="2014-09-23">
                  <entry>data4</entry>
               </result>
            </ds>
         </dataSourceResults>
      </person>
   </matchedResults>
</personData>
```

How can I modify the xsl I have to get the desired transformation?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Formally define "similar" please. Do you mean that given `a_b`, `a` must be the same?

Comment: Have you read the standard article on XSLT 1.0 grouping? http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html